# How to add to map, getting error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am currently writing selenium script for Cucumber in Java.
I am passing some values from feature files.
This values are stored then stored in map.
After this I am trying to add new value in map using put but i am getting error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException.
What am i doing wrong ?

```
public void editFields(DataTable dataTable) {

        Map<String, String> inputData = dataTable.asMaps().get(0);
        String eDate =Utils.getCAProperty("effectiveDate");
        inputData.put("Ef Date", eDate ); // error on this line, not able to add data
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting? It could be an unmodifiable map...

Comment: Look like, this method returns so-called `immuttable map` where mutating methods are just throwing an exception. Read javadoc for asMaps() method, I think it contains this info.

Comment: getting error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: The map is created with the static method java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap as mentioned in earlier comments. -> [Code](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/e774acc622ef7c115637e61f2149569dfd5084a9/datatable/src/main/java/io/cucumber/datatable/DataTableTypeRegistryTableConverter.java#L42). Copy the existing data to your map object.

Comment: How do I add new data then ?

Answer (score 1):

It's usually not a good idea to edit your inputs. You may want to use them unedited in other places too. Rather you should create a new data structure and add your data to that. For example:

```java
Map<String, String> inputData = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // Linked, to preserve order
inputData.putAll(dataTable.asMaps().get(0));
inputData.put("Ef Date", eDate);
```